# Why does mingw-w64 gfortran fail to statically link libraries when the -static flag is passed?

Tags: gfortran, mingw-w64, tdm-mingw

**Disclaimer:** I'm fairly deep into my particular compiling issue but quite new to the world of compiling.

**Background:**
I'm working on a Windows 7, 64 bit machine.  I'm attempting to compile a rather large fortran program using mingw-w64.  The compile process is controlled by SCONS (similar or derived from gnu Make).  I have successfully compiled this program via scons using g95 and mingw gfortran.  I have attempted use tdm-gcc and 'ruben' builds of mingw-w64 with identical, unsatisfactory results.  I am passing the -static argument to the compiler (gfortran.exe).  I have tried using both the gfortran and x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran compile commands with identical results.

**Problem:**
When attempting to compile a 64bit version of my program, despite passing the -static argument to the gfortran compiler, when I attempt to run the built executable, it errors out claiming that it can't find various dll's (libgfortran, libgcc, libquadmath, generically speaking).  If I copy those libraries to the working directory, the built program runs without error and performs as expected.

**Anecdotal Summary:**
mingw-w64 gfortran appears to be ignoring the -static compile flag

If there is any additional information I can provide to help in solving this, please let me know.

Thanks,
JTJ